# How to write own CasperJS modules?

Tags: node.js, functional-testing, casperjs

For example, I have a step that often needs to be executed, eg user login before some test.

How to write reusable chunks of code for CasperJS? Their documentation for extending CasperJS is written only for one file...

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this [issue](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/348) relates fairly well to the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: casperjs is not the part of nodejs ecosystem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple approach. If not familiar with coffeescript, convert it to JS over at js2coffee.

**tests/casper/test.coolPage.coffee**

```
loginModule = require("./test.login")
loginModule.login("test","testPW")

casper.test.comment "Testing cool stuff, should be logged in by now"

casper.thenOpen casper.cli.get("url") + "/myCoolPage", ->
  @test.assertExists '#myCoolDiv'

casper.then () ->
  @test.assertExists '.somethingElse'

casper.run ->
  @test.done()
```

**tests/casper/test.login.coffee**

```
exports.login = (username, password) ->
  casper.test.comment "Loggin in with username \"#{username}\", password \"#{password}\""

  casper.start casper.cli.get("url") + "/login", ->
    @test.assertExists "input[name=username]", "input[name=password]"

  casper.then () ->
    @sendKeys "input[name=username]", username
    @sendKeys "input[name=password]", password
    @click "input[type=submit]"

  casper.then () ->
    #assert you got logged in
```

**running from command line:**

```
cd tests/casper    
casperjs test test.coolPage.coffee --url=http..my-test-url
```

Comment: We've done almost same. Also it's possible to do that without exports and add methods directly to casper instance: `casper.login`.