# Modularized routines with CasperJS

Tags: casperjs

To be able to test my web service, I need to be logged in.

I've wrote a casperjs test for the login funcionality, but I would like to reuse that in all of my future tests.

Is there a way to modularize the login routine I've already wrote, and have it to run at each test's start function?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138761/how-to-write-own-casperjs-modules ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either write a [module](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/writing_modules.html) or [extend the `casper` object](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/extending.html).

In a test context, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/n1k0/3813361) may be useful as well.